# Creating a log of lines which are run in if condition?

Tags: python

I have a python code which has is more than 200 lines. A lot of `if else conditions` are there along with loops
Is there a way to create a logging file which can list all the lines which are run for each of the iterable so that I can get to know in which iteration which `if else condition` was used?

Comment: Having a bunch of if-else is generally considerred a bad practice. But if that's somehow unavoidable you need a debugger to do what you're trying to do. Also it would be better to tell us why you need to know which branch is triggered for each iterable.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve similar functionality as what you're trying to do is by
using an IDE, like PyCharm, or VS Code, setting breakpoints on specific
parts of your code, and then running the code in debug mode.

For example, imagine this is your code with the multiple `for..loops`
and `if..else` statements:

```py
# == Necessary imports =========================================================
import time


# == Auxiliary functions =======================================================
def do_work():
    """Simple function to simulate work done by some process."""
    time.sleep(0.5)

# Same as `do_work` but with a different name.
do_some_more_work = do_work


# == Main program ==============================================================
for value in range(10):
    if value == 0:
        do_work()
    elif value % 2 == 0:
        do_work()
    elif value % 3 == 0:
        do_work()
        if value == 3:
            do_some_more_work()
    else:
        do_work()
```

In that case, you might want to set breakpoints in locations like:

[image]

Note that the lines highlighted and with red circles on the left side represent lines that I've added the breakpoints to.

Then, when you run the code in debug mode, the IDE will stop at the lines with the breakpoints you've set. In the case of PyCharm (but I believe VS Code also does this), whenever you reach a breakpoint, the IDE will also show the defined object's values next to the object itself. Here's what it looks like when a breakpoint is reached:

[image]

---

### Option 2: use `logging`

You could also define a log instance that saves log messages to a file using the `logging` package, and then put `logger.info()` calls after each of the desired `if..else` statements your code has. The problem with this approach is that, as you stated, your code has 200 lines, and you'll have to eventually remove those `logger.info()` calls that you've added to your code.